# Is there a way in Divshot to use includes for global elements?

Tags: bootstrapping, divshot

I'm building a site with 50+ pages and was hoping I could use something such as php includes to bring in global elements like the nav into each page. Is there any way to do something along those lines? Or any time I change a global element will I have to go and copy/paste those changes into each individual page?

Answer (score 0):

Something to address this need is on our roadmap and something we really want as well.

( I am an employee at Divshot. )

Comment: Putting a comment here to look into something.